# variable not being set to correct value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a table using `PHP` from a `jQuery` post method and I am failing miserably.

**PHP/HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td>Name: </td>        
  <td>                  
    <select id="name" onchange="showUserInfo()">  
      <option value="">Please select a person...</option>                       
      <?php $names = getUserName($db); foreach($names as $key => $value) { ?>                        
      <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
      <?php }?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
...
<div id="editUserTable">hi</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function showUserInfo() {
    var str = $('#name option:selected').text(); // THIS VARIABLE IS NOT BEING SET
    $.post('/TrakFlex/functions/getUserInfo.php', { input: str }, function(data) {
        $('#editUserTable').html(data);
    })
}
```

Now I know this variable is not being set because if I replace

```
var str = $('#name option:selected').text();
```

With an actual username like this

```
var str = 'De Bug';
```

Everything works perfectly the table loads into the form with all the user information.

As it is now, the div 'editUserTable' shows "hi" when the form loads but when I select a user "hi" disappears and nothing is showing.

It should be noted I have tried this and it does not work

```
var str = $('#name').val();
```

So again, the question is, why is this variable not being set to the inner HTML or 'text' of the selected `<option>`. Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
If I view the page source after I select a user this is what I see

```
<select id="name" onchange="showUserInfo()">  
  <option value="">Please select a person...</option>                       
  <option value="0">De Bug</option>
  <option value="1">Jon Doe</option>
  <option value="2">A Name</option>                                               
</select>
```

**EDIT 2**

If I hard code the name of the user in my jQuery everything loads in my html page.

this is the original

```
function showUserInfo() {
        var str = $('#name option:selected').text(); // THIS VARIABLE IS NOT BEING SET
        $.post('/TrakFlex/functions/getUserInfo.php', { input: str }, function(data) {
            $('#editUserTable').html(data);
        })
    }
```

if I change it to this, it works

```
function showUserInfo() {
        var str = 'De Bug'; // I can also use 'A Name' or 'Jon Doe' they all work
        $.post('/TrakFlex/functions/getUserInfo.php', { input: str }, function(data) {
            $('#editUserTable').html(data);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Remember to simplify/focus questions. This has *nothing* to do with AJAX: an unexpected value, perhaps. Replace $.post with alert (or use debugger), verify the behavior, and update the question.

Comment: How do you know its not being set?

Comment: PHP is pretty strict with the use of `;`

Comment: @Musa please read the post. It says "Now I know this variable is not being set because if I replace `var str = $('#name option:selected').text();`
With an actual username like this `var str = 'De Bug';`
Everything works perfectly

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan did I miss a `;` or add a `;` somewhere I wasn't supposed to?

Comment: @user2246674 I verified the behavior by simply hard coding the variable and everything works perfectly. I will remove any mention of AJAX as you are correct.

Comment: `Everything works perfectly` is useless information, It seems to me the issue is in your php file.

Comment: @Musa "Everything works perfectly" means the table loads into my form, with all user information. As it says in the original post. I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: And that markup is of course within table tags as well, otherwise you'll get nothing

Comment: @adeneo yes of course. If i just hard code the variable into 'Jon Doe' or 'De Bug' or any of my user names I get everything I want from my `PHP` file. The variable is clearly not being set to the appropriate value because if I pass the appropriate value from hard coding it the form loads with the data I want from my php file

Comment: Can you provide the full code in one piece so we can see in what order everything is done?

Comment: Where are you hard coding the value of `Jon Doe` or `De Bug`? In the `$.post()` or PHP itself?

Comment: in some browsers the event onchange may be fired before the dom is updated, before one is `option:selected` - you may have to lookup the selected option based on `selectedIndex` or `value`

Comment: @metadings - Ah that explains why in my jsFiddle it was not firing, did not know that; I use jQuery for events so much I have never stumbled across this until now.

Comment: @KarlAnderson see 'Edit2' I clarified for you

Comment: @i_me_mine - Even if you change it use jQuery you still get the wrong value from `.text()`?

Comment: Did you try `var str = document.getElementById('name').value;`

Comment: @adeneo yes, that does not work either

Comment: And the function is in the global scope, it's not inside document ready or anything like that.

Comment: You've opened the console (F12), and there are no errors

Comment: @adeneo correct to both

Comment: Then I can only think of two more options, you either disabled javascript in your browser, or you have invalid markup. Copy paste the source you see when rightclicking and view source into [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: Or the third, you're a troll, as there is no way getElementById should fail with that simple code -> http://jsfiddle.net/DCAaK/1/

Comment: I had another element with the id='name'... just kill me, please, seriously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers may fire `onchange` before updating the DOM, so the `option` is currently not `:selected`.

Please try this solution, based on the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element:

```
function showUserInfo() {
    var i = $('#name')[0].selectedIndex;
    var str = $('#name option').eq(i).text();
    $.post('/TrakFlex/functions/getUserInfo.php', { input: str }, function(data) {
        $('#editUserTable').html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: This did not work either. I added an alert below `var str =...` that looks like this alert (str); and it's always blank

Comment: when you do `alert(i);` what does that say?

Comment: you have there a very odd problem. are you sure you have only one element of id `name`?

Comment: OMG! I just did a control F to find anything with the id="name"... there was a field input I totally forgot about with the id="name". Please just kill me now. 3 hours of my life I will never get back. Thank you sir a million times over

Comment: I'm sleeping with ViewSource and Ctrl+F ;) btw. in Firefox you can easily see markup errors, just like validation by W3C but alot faster!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `onchange` not firing from the HTML select, but if you use the jQuery document ready function and then attach to the `change` event for the select, then it will work, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').change(function () {
        var str = $('#name option:selected').text(); // THIS VARIABLE IS NOT BEING SET
        $.post('/TrakFlex/functions/getUserInfo.php', { input: str }, function(data) {
            $('#editUserTable').html(data);
        })
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/futureshock2038/9Cg77/)

I have no idea why the regular JavaScript event is not firing.

Comment: This still isn't working. Is it possibly because of how I'm setting the `<option>` values with $key and $value?

Comment: Well have you viewed the source of your HTML page after the select options render? I do not know anything about PHP so I am of little help with that part, sorry.

Comment: the problem here is the document as metadings mentioned up top. I also tried `$(window).load` and that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem sits where you create your list.

As a value you echo the `$key`. You should be echo-ing `$value` instead.

```
<?php

$names = getUserName($db);
foreach($names as $key => $value) {
    ?><option value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option><?php
}

?>
```

Then just replace the line where you set `str` with:

```
var str = $('#name').val();
```

Comment: I thought you might of had it, unfortunately that does not work either

Comment: I suggest to test using Chrome's console. Does it give any errors?